# jq conditional delete from array

Tags: json, jq, aws-cli, remove-if

I have this json i got from aws, this is just a test i created not my actual rules

```
[
    {
      "Name": "Fortinet-all_rules",
      "Priority": 0,
      "Statement": {
        "ManagedRuleGroupStatement": {
          "VendorName": "Fortinet",
          "Name": "all_rules",
          "ExcludedRules": [
            {
              "Name": "Database-Vulnerability-Exploit-01"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Database-Vulnerability-Exploit-02"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Database-Vulnerability-Exploit-03"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Malicious-Robot"
            },
            {
              "Name": "OS-Command-Injection-01"
            },
            {
              "Name": "OS-Command-Injection-02"
            },
            {
              "Name": "SQL-Injection-01"
            },
            {
              "Name": "SQL-Injection-02"
            },
            {
              "Name": "SQL-Injection-03"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Source-Code-Disclosure"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Application-Injection-01"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Application-Injection-02"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Application-Vulnerability-Exploit-01"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Application-Vulnerability-Exploit-02"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Application-Vulnerability-Exploit-03"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Application-Vulnerability-Exploit-04"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Application-Vulnerability-Exploit-05"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Application-Vulnerability-Exploit-06"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Application-Vulnerability-Exploit-07"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Scanner-01"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Scanner-02"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Scanner-03"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Server-Vulnerability-Exploit-01"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Server-Vulnerability-Exploit-02"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Server-Vulnerability-Exploit-03"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Web-Server-Vulnerability-Exploit-04"
            }
          ],
          "ScopeDownStatement": {
            "RegexPatternSetReferenceStatement": {
              "ARN": "",
              "FieldToMatch": {
                "UriPath": {}
              },
              "TextTransformations": [
                {
                  "Priority": 0,
                  "Type": "NONE"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "OverrideAction": {
        "None": {}
      },
      "VisibilityConfig": {
        "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
        "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
        "MetricName": "Fortinet-all_rules"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "DDOS_rate_rule",
      "Priority": 1,
      "Statement": {
        "RateBasedStatement": {
          "Limit": 350,
          "AggregateKeyType": "FORWARDED_IP",
          "ScopeDownStatement": {
            "NotStatement": {
              "Statement": {
                "IPSetReferenceStatement": {
                  "ARN": "",
                  "IPSetForwardedIPConfig": {
                    "HeaderName": "X-Forwarded-For",
                    "FallbackBehavior": "MATCH",
                    "Position": "FIRST"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "ForwardedIPConfig": {
            "HeaderName": "X-Forwarded-For",
            "FallbackBehavior": "MATCH"
          }
        }
      },
      "Action": {
        "Block": {}
      },
      "VisibilityConfig": {
        "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
        "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
        "MetricName": "DDOS_rate_rule"
      }
    }
  ]
```

So what i want for example is to delete the element  `{ "Name": "OS-Command-Injection-01" }`

I need to do it conditionally
So i tried using select `jq '. |  select([].Statement.ManagedRuleGroupStatement.ExcludedRules[].Name == "Malicious-Robot")'`
problem is it errors jq: error (at :150): Cannot iterate over null (null)
also if i try to chain selects it doesn't work
I will also need to delete several object at once, but if i can delete one i can run the query several times so that's not an issue

Answer (score 3):

`|=` is useful for modifying elements of a data structure.

- The left-hand side should return the things to modify. (Use parens if it contains `|`.)
- The right-hand side is evaluated as if `|` was used instead of `|=`.
- The right-hand side should return the new value. (Use parens if it contains `|`.)
- The whole returns `.` with the modifications made.

```sh
jq '
   ( .[].Statement.ManagedRuleGroupStatement.ExcludedRules | arrays ) |=
      map(select(.Name != "OS-Command-Injection-01"))
'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/O5rNubXvQy)

Comment: that worked great, trying to make it allow multiple deletions nowm failed with using "in" if you have any idea that would be great

Comment: You want `IN`, not `in` (`.Name | IN("A", "B") | not`)

Comment: Also tried ( .[].Statement.ManagedRuleGroupStatement.ExcludedRules | arrays ) |= map(select(.Name IN ("OS-Command-Injection-01", "OS-Command-Injection-02") | not ))
doesn't work jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
( .[].Statement.ManagedRuleGroupStatement.ExcludedRules | arrays ) |= map(select(.Name IN ("OS-Command-Injection-01", "OS-Command-Injection-02") | not ))                                                                                       
jq: 1 compile error
exit status 3, not sure why

Comment: You left out a `|`

Answer (score 1):

To delete objects from arrays, you could use the template:

```
walk(if type == "array”
     then map(select( 
      ( type=="object" and
        (.Name|IN( ... ) ) ) | not ))
     else . end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
jq 'walk(if type=="object" and
            (.Name|IN("OS-Command-Injection-01","SQL-Injection-03"))
         then empty
         else . end)' input-file
```

Comment: that worked, thank you!
Can you tell me if there is a way to remove multiple object like that in 1 go?

Comment: This approach (using `walk` to delete entire objects unconditionally) might seem to work, but it can also produce surprises because  sometimes you’ll end up with `null` where you might want `{}`. Consider e.g. `{"b":{"a":1}}`